# How to fix the Image reference?

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I'm using the Google Cloud Vision API with Python 3, but i'm getting the error
"Cannot find reference 'Image' in types.py" when i use:

```
image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
```

I made the correct imports and the documentation tells me to use this function to get an image. Anyone can help me?

Code:

```
import io
import os
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "C:/Keys/key.json"

client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient

path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "image.jpg")

with io.open(path, "rb") as image_file:
 content = image_file.read()

image = types.Image(content=content)
```

Error Message:

[image: error message]

Google Cloud Vision API version: 0.36.0

Comment: Is this a linter error or is it from running your code? It works fine on my env (google-cloud-vision 0.36.0). How did you import `vision`? Like in this example: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries#using_the_client_library?

Comment: Based on your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNqSY.png), it's just a Python linting error. Your code itself should run fine. Did you try running it? What IDE and linter (ex. pylint, etc.) are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should be importing like this:

```py
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
```

and then you will be able to do this:

```py
image = types.Image(content=content)
```

There is a full tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries). It works on my machine on Python3.7 perfectly fine.

Comment: With the `from google.cloud import vision` import, it is also possible to do  `vision.types.Image`.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code including import lines?